# Heroku PostGres Database Test Config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, heroku

I ran rails test on Heroku and it passed and I went about my day, only to start getting error reports from my alpha users. Turned out the database is empty except a few (not even all) fixtures.

Did the test destroy my production data base? Or am I somehow currently connecting to the test database instead? How can I debug this? How can I fix this? And I can avoid doing this in the future?

Updates:

I can confirm that if I ask the rails console what my production database it says sqlite now and not postgres? SHOULD it say postgres?

Update:
The following is the closest I've found to my issue so far, but the problem is supposed to be fixed in rails 4.1 and beyond, and also has no actual solution. I don't think this is it...

https://forum.upcase.com/t/my-heroku-postgres-production-db-was-emptied-out-how-to-diagnose/4984/7

Comment: Any way I can edit the question to not be on hold? I think my problem is able to still be reproduced and wasn't caused by a simple error if it hasn't been fixed yet?

Answer (score 1):

Check your 'test' environment's database configuration by running this in your `rails console`:

```
Rails.configuration.database_configuration['test']
```

Comment: !!! that helped! it confirmed i'm in a sql test database. any idea how to change back?

Comment: if it is already on test database, why do you need to change back? Issue must be somewhere else then

Comment: I want it to be back on production though. My users are freaking out all the test data is there instead of theirs.

Comment: so you want to run your tests against production database?

Comment: No, I ran some tests and ever since my site seems to be in test mode. Anyone connecting to it is seeing the test database stuff instead of what was there before.

Comment: if the above code displays only the test credentials instead of production credentials, then the issue is not this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184235/discussion-between-jenny-and-emaillenin).